# Problem with the interface of my application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating my own mobile application in Visual Studio Code with Flutter in Dart, when running my registration screen it prevents me from pressing any button (even the back button and the one to upload an image) or field, also part of the card is cut off, check What is the responsible widget that is causing the problem but I can't find it, I would greatly appreciate your help :)

There are the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:test/image_picker_widget.dart';
import 'package:test/registro.dart';

class Registro_perro extends StatefulWidget {
  Registro_perro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Registro_perroState createState() => _Registro_perroState();
}

class _Registro_perroState extends State<Registro_perro> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController _usuarioController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _contrasenaController = TextEditingController();

  File imageFile = File("");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ImagePickerWidget(
            imageFile: this.imageFile,
            onImageSelected: (PickedFile file) {
              setState(() {
                this.imageFile = File(file.path);
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            child: AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            height: kToolbarHeight + 25,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0, -40),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 260),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 35, vertical: 20),
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Nombre:"),
                            controller: _usuarioController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Raza:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Edad:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Genero:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Peso:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Tamaño:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration:
                                InputDecoration(labelText: "Color de pelaje:"),
                            obscureText: true,
                            controller: _contrasenaController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Registro_perro(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Iniciar sesión'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                '¿No estás registrado?      ',
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Registro(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Regístrate'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}v
```

```
-Image Picker Widget:

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

typedef OnImageSelected = Function(PickedFile imageFile);

class ImagePickerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final File imageFile;
  final OnImageSelected onImageSelected;
  ImagePickerWidget({required this.imageFile, required this.onImageSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 320,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 77, 225),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 0, 131),
          ],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: FileImage(imageFile),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        onPressed: () {
          _showPickerOptions(context);
        },
        iconSize: 60,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showPikerOptions(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: Text("Camera"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                _showPikerImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.image),
              title: Text("Galeria"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                _showPikerImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _showPikerImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: source) as PickedFile;
    this.onImageSelected(File(image.path) as PickedFile);
  }
  
  void _showPickerOptions(BuildContext context) {}
}

I tried to make the existing buttons smaller or even delete them and it didn't work. So I think it is some Widget that is causing some overflow of information.
```